# How to save log output of an Azure Pipeline Command Line task

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am using a Command Line task to invoke an exe which outputs a log to standard output. How can I  publish this output (command line tasks' log) as an artifact?

```
TabularEditor.exe "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyModel"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the redirect STDOUT and point at the artifact staging directory. Then use an artifact publish task.

e.g.

```
TabularEditor.exe "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyModel" > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\bpa_result.log
```